# WordPress theme templates are managed by PHP can't create new template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes

My work's WordPress theme appears to be coded in PHP that has the "Classic Editor" plugin activated and manages content via hooked in windows at the bottom each page in edit mode (underneath a blank Classic Editor)
[image: Content Management Windows]

I have never worked with a theme like this before. I want to disable the classic editor plugin and create a new template that simply pulls in the current theme's header & footer, plus any page content via the WP loop.

there are two files (in subsequent posts) that seem to manage the themes page templates: PageRenderer php & PageRendererinterface php

I have coded a new template:

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Template test
    */
    use Frank\PageRenderer\PageRenderer;

    // Get the default wordpress header
    get_header();

    $renderer = new PageRenderer();


   $renderer->setSingular((is_single() || is_page()));

   if (have_posts()) {
      while (have_posts()) {
       the_post();

        $renderer->addPost($post);
    }
  }
  $renderer->render(); 
  get_footer();

   ?>
```

This is just causing a white screen. Would love to know what framework this "PageRenderer" coding is using so I can reference how to disable the reliance on the classic code editor and get a template that can use blocks for the content.

Pagerender

```
     <?php
 namespace Frank\PageRenderer;
 
 use Frank\PageRenderer\PageRendererInterface;
 /**
 * Dynamically pick the correct page template to render, based on the post type
 */
 class PageRenderer implements PageRendererInterface {
 
     use \Frank\Traits\FormatPageTemplate;
     use \Frank\Traits\GetClassAcrossNamespaces;
 
     /**
      * The template renderer to use in order to display the page
      *
      * @var Frank\TemplateRenderer\TemplateRendererInterface the template renderer
      */
     protected $templateRenderer = null;
 
     /**
      * Determine if the page is a single page or a listing page
      *
      * @var boolean
      */
     protected $isSingular = true;
     /**
      * Determine if the page is a 404
      *
      * @var boolean
      */
     protected $is404 = false;
 
     /**
      * The list of posts to process
      *
      * @var array<WP_Post>
      */
     protected $posts = [];
 
     public function setSingular($isSingular) {
         $this->isSingular = !!($isSingular);
     }
 
     public function setIs404($is404) {
         $this->is404 = !!($is404);
     }
 
     public function setTemplateRenderer(\Frank\TemplateRenderer\TemplateRendererInterface $templateRenderer) {
         $this->templateRenderer = $templateRenderer;
     }
 
     public function addPost(\WP_Post $post) {
         $this->posts[] = $post;
     }
 
     public function render() {
 
         if ($this->is404) {
             // Handle the 404 template case
             $template404 =  $this->getClassAcrossNamespaces('TemplateRenderer\TemplateRenderer_404');
             $this->templateRenderer = new $template404();
         } else if ($this->isSingular) {
             if (count($this->posts) > 0) {
                 // Automatically assign a template renderer when singular page
            $className = defined('APP_TEMPLATE_RENDERER') ? APP_TEMPLATE_RENDERER : $this->getTemplateRendererClass($this     ->posts[0]);
 
                 //Check if the class implements the TemplateRendererInterface
                 $interfaces = class_implements($className);
                 if (isset($interfaces['Frank\TemplateRenderer\TemplateRendererInterface'])) {
                     $this->templateRenderer = new $className($this->posts[0]);
                 }else{
                throw new \Exception("TemplateRenderer {$className} doesn't implement      Frank\TemplateRenderer\TemplateRendererInterface.");
                 }
             } else {
                 throw new \Exception("No post available for PageRenderer.");
             }
         } else {
             // Check if a template renderer is set, otherwise, assign one automatically
             if (defined('APP_ARCHIVE_TEMPLATE_RENDERER')) {
                 $className = APP_ARCHIVE_TEMPLATE_RENDERER;
                 $interfaces = class_implements($className);
                 if (isset($interfaces['Frank\TemplateRenderer\TemplateRendererInterface'])) {
                     $this->templateRenderer = new $className();
                 }else{
                throw new \Exception("TemplateRenderer {$className} doesn't implement      Frank\TemplateRenderer\TemplateRendererInterface.");
                 }
             } else if (is_null($this->templateRenderer)) {
                 $this->templateRenderer = new \Frank\TemplateRenderer\TemplateRenderer_archive_default();
             }
         }
 
         if ($this->templateRenderer) {
             $result = $this->templateRenderer->render();
             echo $result;
         } else {
             throw new \Exception("No TemplateRenderer available for PageRenderer.");
         }
     }
 
     /**
      * Get the template rendering class
      *
      * Will first check if there is a rendering class in app then in frank.
      * If none is found, will throw an error
      *
      * @throws \Exception If no template renderer class is found
      * @param \WP_Post the post
      * @return string the class
      */
     protected function getTemplateRendererClass(\WP_Post $post) {
 
         $postType = str_replace('-', '_', $post->post_type);
         $templateName = $this->formatPageTemplate($post->ID);
         $partialClassName = "TemplateRenderer\\TemplateRenderer_{$postType}_{$templateName}";
 
         $className = $this->getClassAcrossNamespaces($partialClassName);
 
         if (is_null($className)) {
             throw new \Exception("TemplateRenderer {$partialClassName} type not found.");
         }
 
         return $className;
     }
 
 }
 
 ?>
```

PageRendererInterface

```
     <?php
 namespace Frank\PageRenderer;
 
 interface PageRendererInterface {
 
     /**
      * Set if the page renderer should be configured for a single page or a listing page
      *
      * @param boolean $isSingular true if a single page, false otherwise
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function setSingular($isSingular);
 
     /**
      * Set if the page is a 404
      *
      * @param boolean $is404 true if a 404 page
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function setIs404($is404);
 
     /**
      * Add a post to the renderer
      *
      * @param \WP_Post $post The post to add to the renderer
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function addPost(\WP_Post $post);
 
     /**
      * Render the page sections
      *
      * Output the string
      *
      * @throws Exception if no TemplateRenderer class is found for the post
      * @throws Exception if the TemplateRenderer class doesn't implement the TemplateRendererInterface
      * @return void
      */
     public function render();
 }
 
 ?>
```

Comment: Screen options upper right corner - hide content

Comment: Thanks @Martin Michev the problem once the classic editor is disabled. On a new page any content entered via the Block Editor does not render in the content area between the page header & footer